# How to display the large tab bar name in the tab bar item

Tags: iphone

I created a tab bar controller with 3 tab bar items and the tab bar items names are very large and they are displaying names on one over the other. i want to display the name in short way. for example: tab bar item name is: ("Iphone Real Device") i want to display it as (Iphone...) Can any one help me in this issue please......

Thanks in advance..........

Comment: not possible to do so.. it will add ... at the end automatically.. so u have to take short text

Comment: it is not adding ...at the end. the text is over writing on other tab bar item name.

Answer (score 0):

Make it programitically. set the frame for tabBar and then add the tabs to the taBar. it automatically uses .... if your text is bigger that the tab frame.

Edit: I think you cant set the frame for tabs. so you need to hard code the title like this

blab..

Comment: can you tell me the steps to set the frame please. I am new to the iphone coding. It will be a lot helpful to me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220978/how-to-create-a-tabbar-programmatically-and-adding-buttons-on-it use this link for creating tabBar programitically.