# Why can't I edit the height of a UITabBar in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I added `UITabBar` in `storyboard`, but it's a bit too short for me because I want to have two `UIButton`s there, why cant I adjust the `width`?

[image]

And how can I add a UITabBar with bat button item programatically..?

tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITabbar' height is defined by Apple and cannot be changed according to HIG [HIG Developers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW1)

For the second part of your question you can check this post.

[How to create TabBar programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220978/2838161)

Answer (score 0):

`Tabbar` height is `Fixed` and you are not supposed to change it. That's why it is grayed out. if u need to change the height in the place use custom `UIButton`